# Python/Selenium, xpath suddenly stops working

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, error-handling

I have a script that extracts names from a crypto list on coinmarketcap. To get the names I use the function:

```py
num = 0
def print_name():
    global num
    num = num + 1
    if num == 100:
         exit()
    sleep(0.1)
    names = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr['+str(num)+']/td[3]/div/a/div/div/div/p')
    print(names.text)
```

To go through the list, there is a number I have to change which is `+str(num)+` in the xpath so the xpath moves to the next name in the list every time, but at number 18 the script just randomlly stops working and gives an error:

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

**even though the xpath stays the same**, I checked multiple times, made the driver refresh, even scroll down to maybe load the data but the program just doesn't recognize the path.

- It is not because the website blocks the automation, I tried beginning with the number 5, so I make less requests before reaching number 18 but it still didn't work.

Here is the Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fkahd\PycharmProjects\coingecko api\sandbox.py", line 27, in <module>
    print_name()
  File "C:\Users\fkahd\PycharmProjects\coingecko api\sandbox.py", line 23, in print_name
    names = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr['+str(num)+']/td[3]/div/a/div/div/div/p')
  File "C:\Users\fkahd\PycharmProjects\coingecko api\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1244, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\fkahd\PycharmProjects\coingecko api\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\fkahd\PycharmProjects\coingecko api\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[18]/td[3]/div/a/div/div/p"}
  (Session info: chrome=98.0.4758.82)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00557AC3+2587331]
    Ordinal0 [0x004EADD1+2141649]
    Ordinal0 [0x003E3BB8+1063864]
    Ordinal0 [0x004101CE+1245646]
    Ordinal0 [0x004103CB+1246155]
    Ordinal0 [0x0043A612+1418770]
    Ordinal0 [0x004286D4+1345236]
    Ordinal0 [0x00438A0A+1411594]
    Ordinal0 [0x004284A6+1344678]
    Ordinal0 [0x004053F6+1201142]
    Ordinal0 [0x004062E6+1204966]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x006FDF22+1680738]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x007B0DBC+2413564]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x005ED151+563089]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x005EBF13+558419]
    Ordinal0 [0x004F081E+2164766]
    Ordinal0 [0x004F5508+2184456]
    Ordinal0 [0x004F5650+2184784]
    Ordinal0 [0x004FF5BC+2225596]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x764AFA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77BB7A9E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77BB7A6E+238]
```

It says: Unable to locate element: `{"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[18]/td[3]/div/a/div/div/div/p"}`

But, when I go to inspect element, the path is

`/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[18]/td[3]/div/a/div/div/div/p`

Which is **exactly** the same as the one in error message.

Html of text:
`<p color="text3" class="sc-1eb5slv-0 gGIpIK coin-item-symbol" font-size="1">SCRT</p>`

Full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://coinmarketcap.com/view/defi/")
sleep(2)
driver.refresh()

num = 0
num2 = 17

def loop2():
    global num2
    global names2
    num2 = num2 + 1
    if num2 == 100:
        exit()
    sleep(0.1)
    names2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr['+str(num2)+']/td[3]/div/a/div/div/div/p')

def print_name():
    global num
    num = num + 1
    if num == 18:
         loop2()
    sleep(0.1)
    names = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr['+str(num)+']/td[3]/div/a/div/div/div/p')
    print(names.text)

while True:
    print_name()
```

Quick update here are an example of xpath 17 and 18, but 18 doesn't work:

`/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[18]/td[3]/div/a/div/div/div/p`

`/html/body/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[17]/td[3]/div/a/div/div/div/p`

Thanks for your help, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the names from the Top DeFi Tokens by Market Capitalization within [Coinmarketcap](https://coinmarketcap.com/view/defi/) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://coinmarketcap.com/view/defi/")
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "p[class$='coin-item-symbol']")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://coinmarketcap.com/view/defi/")
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//p[contains(@class, 'coin-item-symbol')]")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```